# Elementary question about finite sums of powers of all positive integers less than n.

Tags: number-theory

Does the equation $$\left(1 + 2^{x} + \dots  n^{x}\right)^{y}= 1 + 2^{x + y}+ \dots n^{x+y}$$
$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, have any other integer solution than $x=1,y=2?$

Comment: are x, y integer, real?

Comment: For any positive integer $n$ ?

Comment: When x = 1,y=2 the formula (n(n+1)/2)^{2} gives both side of the equation regardless of n. I am wondering if there are other x,y and other formula giving the above equivalence, regardless of n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are positive integers greater than $1$ , then we have for $n>1$ :

$$(1+2^x+\cdots n^x)^y>1+2^{xy}+\cdots +n^{xy}\ge 1+2^{x+y}+\cdots +n^{x+y}$$

because of $xy\ge x+y$

If $y=1$, the equation is obiously not satisfied.
If $x=1$, we have $$(1+2+\cdots +n)^y=1+2^{y+1}+\cdots +n^{y+1}$$
For $n=2$, we have $(1+2)^y=3^y=1+2^{y+1}$ , which has no solution for $y>2$ according to the (proven) Catalan-conjecture.

So, there is no further pair $(x,y)$ doing the job and probably even no further triple $(x,y,n)$ with positive integers and $n>1$ satisfying the given equation.

Answer (score 0):

Take $n=2$. Then $(1+2^x)^y=1+2 ^{x+y}$. Using Newton's binomial we have $xy \lt x + y$ and, from here $x=1, \forall y$ or $y=1, \forall x$. Should be easy from here to prove $x=1,y=2$ for $n=2$ so the equality becomes $(1 + 2 + ... + n)^2=1 + 2^3 + ... + n^3$ which is easy to prove.